# How to plot a 3d array with R

Tags: arrays, r, plot, 3d

In parallel to plotting a 2d matrix with image() I am looking for an command to plot a 3d array within R

**2d Example gives a 2d-plot**

```
x<-matrix(runif(25),nrow=5,ncol=5)
image(x)
```

---

**3d Question: is there a way to for plotting this 3d array**

```
x<-array(runif(125),dim=c(5,5,5))
```

The resulting plot should show a cube and the argument for the cube should be the array

Comment: If there is no solution within R, I am also interested in a Python solution

Comment: None of the functions that plot data in 3D are insufficient?

Comment: @Roman: I don't understand. Do you mean that every function that plot data in 3D is sufficient?

Comment: Bah, I meant "sufficient". Can I plead the fifth? :)

Comment: So I give up, Your Honour