# R: How to plot a 3D array

Tags: r

I want to plot a 3D array **M** where

```
M <- array(runif(64),dim=c(4,4,4))
```

A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329658/how-to-plot-a-3d-array-with-r) with comments that this can be done using a common 3D plot in R, but I could find no such function in R which can be used to plot multidimensional arrays (say, a 3D array as in the above example). Any suggestion how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you want to plot? Points coloured according to the value of M at 64 locations in a 3d cube?

Comment: @Spacedman. Yes. Deleted the unnecessary part.

Comment: Why are the coordinates of the points unneccessary? Do you want to plot the points at coordinates 1:4 instead on all three axes?

Comment: @Spacedman. Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `melt` to create a table of x,y,z,value, and then `rgl` to do a 3d plot:

```
library(reshape2)
library(rgl)
M=melt(M)
points3d(M$Var1,M$Var2,M$Var3)
```

That's just 64 points in a cube. You can scale and colour them:

```
points3d(M$Var1,M$Var2,M$Var3,size=10,color=rainbow(10)[M$value*10])
```

Use whatever method of mapping `M$value` to colour you prefer. Don't use rainbow palettes for real!